# How to tell whether sys.stdout has been flushed in Python

Tags: python, io, stdout

I'm trying to debug some code I wrote, which involves a lot of parallel processes. And have some unwanted behaviour involving output to `sys.stdout` and certain messages being printed twice. For debugging purposes it would be very useful to know whether at a certain point `sys.stdout` has been flushed or not. I wonder if this is possible and if so, how?

Ps. I don't know if it matters but I'm using OS X (at least some `sys` commands depend on the operating system).

Comment: Flushed or not, sys.stdout isn't going to give you guaranteed ordering between processes (and it might not even between threads in the same process). Why not add accurate timestamps and log messages separately from each, or, even better, have all of them send debug messages via a threadsafe or interprocess queue?

Comment: The problem is that the same output occurs twice, so adding timestamps e.t.c. will not really help. Also changing sys.stdout to something custom doesn't help since this is really a problem with the buffer. If I start all involved python processes with the -u flag I don't get the problem. I would like to know what exactly is going on instead of just always flushing after some IO happend, since that would just be an ugly workaround without understanding the core of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: you cannot tell (not without serious uglyness, an external C module or similar).

The reason is that python’s file-implementation is based on the C (stdio) implementation for `FILE *`. So an underlying python file object basically just has a reference to the opened `FILE`. When writing data the C-implementation writes data, and when you tell it to `flush()` python also just forwards the flush call. So python does not hold the information. Even for the underlying C layer, a quick search returned that there is no documented API allowing you to access this information, however it's probably somewhere in the `FILE` object, so it could in theory be read out if it is that desperately needed.

Comment: Thanks, to bad that it's so much trouble if possible at all. Since I wanted to know this for debug pruposes only, I just decideded to ad sys.stdout.flush() statements and see if the behaviour of my program changed. If it changed I assumed that it was not flushed at that point.